# Reopen link constantly plays the opening dialogue animation on error

Tags: bug, status-completed, error-message

If you attempt to cast a re-open vote on a question that you have already voted to re-open, you get a red error box that requires manual dismissal (as expected).  However once you dismiss it the three bar loading animation stays on the page indefinitely:

[image: Persisting dotty thing]

They also stack on to each other:

[image: They also stack with themselves]

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.